# AngularJS ng-repeat update does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and I try to Update my Table, made with ng-repeat. But it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.customers = function(){
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: $rootScope.webApiUrl+"/customers/"+$rootScope.session,
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function requestSuccess(response){
        $scope.customerData = response.data;
        console.log($scope.customerData);
        $scope.customerDataReady = true;            
    }, function requestError(response){
        if(response.status == 404)
        {

        }
        else if(response.status == 500)
        {
            alert("Database Error");
        }
    });
}

$scope.saveNewCustomer = function(){
    [...]
    $scope.customers();
}


<div ng-controller="customerCtrl" ng-init="customers()">
    <!--- Space for Javascript --->
    <script src="module/customer/js/customer.js"></script>
    <!--- Javascript End --->
    <!--- Space for Modals --->
    <div ng-include="'module/customer/html/customerDetails.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'module/customer/html/customerAddressNew.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'module/customer/html/customerNew.html'"></div>
    <!--- Modals End -->
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customerNew"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;New Customer</button>
    <hr>
    <p>List of all Customers</p>
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchCustomer" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Customer">
    <br />
    <div>
        <div ng-if="customerDataReady">
            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive table-list">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Zip</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Mail</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="customer in customerData | filter:searchCustomer" ng-click="customerDetails(customer.customerid)">
                    <td>{{customer.customerid}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.address}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.zip}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.city}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.country}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.mail}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I see, that the scope.customerData gets updated correctly, but the Table does not!

Do you have any Ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Tough to say without a jsfiddle. Can you check if it works by removing the filter expression ?

Comment: What if you define the data first in your controller? `$scope.customerData = [];`

Comment: @Tushar: Does not work :(

Comment: @devqon: It doesnt work also :(

Comment: Make sure the response.data is actually an array. Can you confirm ?

Comment: Instead of `ng-if="customerDataReady"` this use `ng-show="customerDataReady"` ! try this and let us know if it works

Comment: We'll really need more detail to help you. Can you be more specific about what does and does not happen? For example, do you see the table heading row? Can you include a sample of the data that's being assigned to `$scope.customerData`?

Comment: This logic seems a bit odd.  If I am reading that JavaScript correctly, when you save a customer, you first run the code to save (code redacted in the question), and then you run code to fetch the entire array of customers from the database again.  The second step seems unnecessary, and seems to be exactly the kind of thing angular is designed to avoid.

Comment: Also, the `saveNewCustomer` seems, from what you are showing in the HTML, be being called from a modal.  Are these two functions in the same controller as the `ng-repeat`, or in a different controller for the modal? It is entirely possible that you are updating a different `$scope`.  As others have said, you really haven't given enough info here to know what is going wrong.

Comment: So the problem is: This will be a list, that is open on about 10 Clients at the same time. As soon as one of them Changes something the list has to update. So after saving a Customer the list should update as a test, to run the Update Function every 10 Seconds or something, so that everyone has the correct information all the time. 

I will prepare testdata for you!